# Is `pytz` deprecated now or in the future in Python?

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz, zoneinfo

[pytz](https://pytz.sourceforge.net/) is used in **the Django version: <=3.2 doc** [Selecting the current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) as shown below:

```py
import pytz # Here

from django.utils import timezone

class TimezoneMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        tzname = request.session.get('django_timezone')
        if tzname:
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzname))
        else:
            timezone.deactivate()
        return self.get_response(request)
```

But, [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) is used instead of `pytz` in **the Django version: 4.0<= doc** [Selecting the current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) as shown below:

```py
import zoneinfo # Here

from django.utils import timezone

class TimezoneMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        tzname = request.session.get('django_timezone')
        if tzname:
            timezone.activate(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(tzname))
        else:
            timezone.deactivate()
        return self.get_response(request)
```

My questions:

1. Is `pytz` deprecated now or in the future in Python?
2. Why isn't `pytz` used in **the Django version: 4.0<= doc** [Selecting the current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone)?

Comment: To quote pytz's readme: *"This project is in maintenance mode. Projects using Python 3.9 or later are best served by using the timezone functionaly now included in core Python and packages that work with it such as tzdata"* https://pypi.org/project/pytz/

Comment: @slothrop I checked `https://github.com/stub42/pytz` but I couldn't find `This project is in maintenance mode. ...`.

Comment: https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/master/src/README.rst, under "Issues & Limitations".

Comment: @slothrop I think that would be good to write up as an answer

Answer (score 5):

To quote [`pytz`'s README](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/master/src/README.rst#issues--limitations):

> This project is in maintenance mode. Projects using Python 3.9 or later are best served by using the timezone functionaly now included in core Python and packages that work with it such as tzdata.

Without using the literal word "deprecated", the package maintainer is proposing that you don't use `pytz` for new projects, so that's really deprecation for all intents and purposes.

So Django's strategy is consistent with that, and in fact Django goes a bit further by facilitating the use of `zoneinfo` in Python 3.8 (the oldest Python version still supported). From [the Django 4.0 documentation you cited](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone):

> Time zone support uses `zoneinfo`, which is part of the Python standard library from Python 3.9. The `backports.zoneinfo` package is automatically installed alongside Django if you are using Python 3.8.

and

> Changed in Django 4.0: `zoneinfo` was made the default timezone implementation. You may continue to use `pytz` during the 4.x release cycle via the `USE_DEPRECATED_PYTZ` setting.